Can't print anymore since last update
Using Ubuntu 20.04 with a Brother DCP-J752DW on USB for years.
CUPS seem broken since last update.
The printer configuration does't run any more.


Have you tried accessing the CUPS GUI by pointing your browser to http://localhost:631/admin  ?

Can't access http://localhost:631/admin

Looks like we have issues at both upstream - https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/985
and
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/2070315
for the ubuntu packages. So an update can be expected soon to fix this regression.

Update just now: every thing ok, print and scanner back.

I have/had the same issue.
I did an upgrade this morning (26 juin) and got the same pop-up when I run "printers".
I had a look in the error log /var/log/cups/error_log and commented out the following lines at the end of the /etc/cups/cupsd.conf file:
#JobPrivateAccess default  
#JobPrivateValues default  
#SubscriptionPrivateAccess default  
#SubscriptionPrivateValues default  

Then I had to change two lines at the top of the /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
file, so I changed
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock  
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock  

to
Listen localhost:631  
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock  

(I suspect that the cups.sock version isn't actually working)
NOTE:
You have to do these edits as root.
When I started cups - service cups start
the "printers" program gave me the printers I'm used to seeing.
And I can connect to http://localhost:631/.
I have no idea why it stopped working and I have just made the changes needed to get it working again. If anyone has more detailed knowledge, I'd be happy to read it here.
BTW:
While the cups server wasn't running Atril Document Viewer (1.24.0) was able to print (but with limited facilities, no double sided printing for example) - It looks like it could find the (HP) printer ports or something.
And now I am starting to understand why "printers" (via CtrlP) has the printers listed twice. [I think I am starting to understand. . .]
Anyway, I hope this helps.

Thanks for the quick workaround tips !
